# PHP POST not Working on Submit FORM ["amount"]=> string(0) ""

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, dump

I am trying to use textbox and multiply using JQuery and trying to save the value into PHP Variable.

one text box is amount in USD and i am trying to multipe it by local currency rate.

Here is the code HTML

```
      <form action="#" method="POST" id="easyPayStartForm">
      <input name="storeId" value="
            <?php echo $storeId; ?>" hidden="true" />
      <input name="amount" value="
                <?php echo $amount; ?>" hidden="true" />
      <input name="postBackURL" value="
                    <?php echo $postBackURL; ?>" hidden="true" />
      <input name="orderRefNum" value="
                        <?php echo $orderRefNum; ?>" hidden="true" />
      <input type="hidden" name="expiryDate" value="
                            <?php echo $expiryDate; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="autoRedirect" value="
                                <?php echo $autoRedirect; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="paymentMethod" value="
                                    <?php echo $paymentMethod; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="emailAddr" value="
                                        <?php echo $emailAddr; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="mobileNum" value="
                                            <?php echo $mobileNum; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="merchantHashedReq" value="
                                                <?php echo $hashRequest; ?>">
<input type="text" id="firstNumber" name="text22" class="form-control ml-1" placeholder="0">
 <input type="text" name="newtxt" id="result1" class="amount">
   <button type="submit" id="sbt" class="btn btn-primary button">Submit</button>
    
       
    </form>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    $('#orderref').val(timestamp);

    $("#firstNumber").keyup(function() {
      is also possible instead of "keyup()"
        var input_value = parseFloat($("#firstNumber").val()); 

        if (!isNaN(input_value)) { // the input is a number
            var newnum = (input_value * 182);
            $("#result").text(newnum.toFixed(1)); 
            //$("#amount").val(newnum.toFixed(1));
            $("#result1").val(newnum.toFixed(1));
        } else { // the input wasn't a number
            $("#result").val("not a number?"); 
        }




    });


});
```

PHP :

```
ob_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
    var_dump($_POST);
   
    $hashRequest = '';
     $hashKey = 'abcede'; // generated from easypay account
    $storeId="1234";
    $int = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'text22', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    $amount= $int ;

DUMP : 

    array(13) { ["storeId"]=> string(4) "123" ["amount"]=> string(0) "" ["postBackURL"]=> string(44) "abvbc" ["orderRefNum"]=> string(10) "1640307967" ["expiryDate"]=> string(138) "
```

Trying to get textbox value here but not working showing string instead of value and integer

```
["amount"]=> string(0) ""
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks like there is code missing. Are you sending this to the server via ajax? I assume so since there are many form variables not referenced in your var_dump($_POST)

Comment: Not using Ajax.
The other variables are working properly and in the last of dump 
["text22"]=> string(4) "10.2" ["optradio"]=> string(2) "on" ["newtxt"]=> string(6) "1856.4" }

The values are correct but not on the actual variable

Comment: Even if i echo the variable its shows the correct value but when i use the form action url to proceed it dsnt past the variable to the form.

Comment: Yes i am using 'name' not the 'id'

Comment: `$("#amount")` will reference to DOM element with `id="amount"` but you use `name=amount` attribute to point element to. Change `$("#amount").val(newnum.toFixed(1));` to `$("[name=amount]").val(newnum.toFixed(1));` or add `id="amount"` attribute to your input element

Comment: @diavolic, That line is commented and not in use.

Answer (score 0):

This line is tripping you up:

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'text22', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)
```

Looking at your variable, I think you want FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT - but even still you'll run into the same issue. The filter_input returns false or null when the filter doesn't succeed, so why not just force the value into the type you want

```
$amount = floatVal($_POST['newtxt'])
```

Comment: Its showing the correct value in dump but when submitting form the value become 0

Comment: Okay so it did work for one time, everything went through but if i come back and try again i didnt work.

What could be the issue any idea?

Comment: Also if i give any static value it works ! like $ amount="10.0"